# How to update a DynamoDB Document (JSON) atomically?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an attribute in my table that is of type Document (JSON) where the value is a count:

```
{ "item1" : "5", "item2" : "7" }
```

Is there a way for the DynamoDB Document API to increment the values of the map atomically? My application will have several hosts incrementing the values, so simply using `puts` will not work as they will overwrite each other.

I know for integer attributes, we can have atomic counting with `set #count = #count + :countVal` in the update expression. Is there something similar for working with Documents?

Also, I noticed that there is no way for `DynamoDBMapper` to make atomic counter updates, so I do have to use the lower level Document API, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have one of your attributes as a Map, with key value pairs in your table. Dynamodb supports document paths in expressions. So you can do

```
doc.item1 = doc.item1 + :countVal
```

You are correct in that dynamodbmapper doesn't support atomic counter updates. It seems to be pretty common to use a combination of dynamodbmapper and lower level API though.

Comment: What if I have a map like this: { "1.50" : 5, "2.50", 7 }? Since the deference operator for a map is a dot, it doesn't seem like I can access maps where the keys are integers?

Comment: Never mind, I just discovered I can use expression attribute names to get around this.